# How to prevent JavaFX ListView from being preselected?

Tags: java, listview, user-interface, javafx

I'm new to JavaFX, so this might be a trivial question. I have a ListView inside a dialog that shows when the user clicks a menu button. The problem is that when the dialog shows, the first item in the ListView is already selected. I have `listView.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<NewChoices>())` as the listener for when a user selects an item, but since the first item is already selected, when I click on the first item nothing happens. I need to find a way to make sure that no item is selected when the dialog shows. I tried using `listView.getSelectionModel().clearSelection()` before showing the dialog, but if the program loses then regains focus, the first item is selected again without being clicked on. How can I prevent the first item, or any item for that matter, being preselected?

Here is the code:

```
    Pane rootPane = new Pane();
    ObservableList<NewChoices> listChoices = FXCollections.observableArrayList(NewChoices.values());
    ListView<NewChoices> listView = new ListView<NewChoices>();
    listView.setItems(listChoices);
    rootPane.getChildren().add(listView);
    Stage newDialog = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
    newDialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
    newDialog.setTitle("New");
    Scene newDialogScene = new Scene(rootPane);
    newDialog.setScene(newDialogScene);
    newDialog.show();
```

Comment: What API are you using to show the dialogs? JDK8_40? ControlsFX? Custom scene? Are there any more controls besides the list on that dialog?

Comment: I'm using JDK8_24 I think. I'm away from my computer right now so I can't remember the exact one, but it's JDK8_2something. And no, it's just the listview in the dialog.

Comment: Since there are not dialogs yet until 8u40, I take that what you call a dialog is just a regular scene. If you have only a list there (no buttons to close the so called dialog?), my guess is when the scene gains the focus, as the only focusable node is the list, its first item gets selected. Adding some OK/Cancel buttons may help since they can gain the focus instead. Maybe you could add a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The dialog is just a regular stage and scene, but it only has an exit button in the top right, and it blocks input to the rest of the program. I will try adding some OK/Cancel buttons and see if that works. If I'm still having trouble I'll post the code here so that you can see where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I tried adding a button but it didn't help. I'll post some of the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Should be fixed in 8u40 - see https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-38517

Comment: That's no use to me now.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have only a list on your new scene, with no buttons, when the scene gains the focus, as the only focusable node is the list, its first item gets selected.

Adding some OK/Cancel buttons may help since they can gain the focus instead, but for that they need to gain first the focus.

Any of these two options will work:

- Put first the button, so its the first focusable node:

  ```
  listView.setItems(listChoices);
  Button button = new Button("Ok");

  VBox rootPane = new VBox(10, button, listView);

  Stage newDialog = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
  newDialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
  newDialog.setTitle("New");
  Scene newDialogScene = new Scene(rootPane);
  newDialog.setScene(newDialogScene);
  newDialog.show();
  ```
- Remove temporaly the focusable property of the list:

  ```
  listView.setItems(listChoices);
  listView.setFocusTraversable(false);

  Button button = new Button("Ok");
  VBox rootPane = new VBox(10, listView, button);
  Stage newDialog = new Stage(StageStyle.UTILITY);
  newDialog.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
  newDialog.setTitle("New");
  Scene newDialogScene = new Scene(rootPane);
  newDialog.setScene(newDialogScene);
  newDialog.show();

  listView.setFocusTraversable(true);
  ```

In any case, both require an extra node. Anyway you will need it to close the modal stage, right?

If you still want to go without buttons, you could use JDK 8u40 early versions where the problem has already been fixed, as @wzberger points out, or if this is not possible, use ControlsFX new [Dialogs](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/openjfx-dialogs/overview) API (a fork of the API that will ship in JDK 8u40), and you won't have any problem.

```
    listView.setItems(listChoices);
    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
    dialog.getDialogPane().setContent(listView);

    Optional<ButtonType> result = dialog.showAndWait();
```

Comment: I don't need an extra node to close the modal stage. It has an exit button already. Ideally I'd not have to have an extra node. Are you sure there's no other way around the problem?

Comment: I don't see that button, where do you put it?

Comment: I didn't put it in myself, it's automatically there, like the maximise/minimise buttons on a regular stage.

Comment: As @wzberger said, it's a bug... I've showed you three different workarounds. If you ask me, I wouldn't have a modal window without ok/cancel buttons. So adding one there at the bottom to close the stage shouldn't be a problem for you.